# Firefox offline "reader view" to show whole scicomp page, including answers

Tags: feature-request

Firefox android has a "reader view", based on readability.js, that is the only way for it to save a page for offline browsing. (You first click the stylized-book icon within the address bar at the right end, and then use the "⋮" menu to select the star icon - the page will then appear within an expandable "Reading list" section. at the top of your "bookmarks" page.)  This firefox feature has a really terrible UI, complex and undiscoverable, but the result *is* readable, and latex is faithfully rendered.

But it only shows the question on scicomp pages... and not the answers (or comments). It's the answers that it would be convenient to be able to study/consult off-line.

I tried a workaround of linking to an answer directly (using "share"), but this gives a location within the same page, and so "reader view" again only shows the question.

I also tried another Stack Exchange (physics), and it has the same behaviour - so I'm guessing this is general to the stackexchange platform, not specific to scicomp.

Arguably, this is firefox's problem... but whatever the cause, I think being able to view answers offline would be a wonderful feature!

Answer (score 3):

Use "save as pdf" for a complete offline copy:

```
⋮ menu > Page > Save as PDF
```

Works in version 53 of Firefox for Android.

You can also use share in that ⋮ menu (a sort of "<" sign with dots at the vertices), but seems to requires a login to Acrobat.

PS: I'd forgotten about this method, but thought I'd answer my own question instead of deleting, in case it's useful to someone else.